# The del function in the for loop removes every second element. I want to delete all of them until the condition is met

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, del

a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0]

for i in a:
if i < 3:
del a[0]

print(a)
[0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

should be:

[3,4,0,0]

Comment: Please be more clear. Which language are you using? What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `i` in a confusing way, since you're not using it as an index (which is kinda the norm) but as an iterator. Just for readability I would suggest changing the iterator name to something more descriptive.

If I understand you're question correctly, you want to delete the first element, until it is bigger or equal 3. If that is your question, you could do it like this:

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0]
while a[0]<3:
    del a[0]
print(a) # [3,4,0,0]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4]
n= []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if(a[i]<3):
        continue
    else:
        n.append(a[i])
print(n) # [3,4]
```

Comment: Thank you but i need delete i<3 only until this condition is met.

Comment: [0,0,0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0,0] gives answer [3,4,0,0,0].